# Parsing arbitrary column limits in text file to load as data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to load in a .DAT text file into R. The data is structured, but in a rather arbitrary way. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
00010         L           1957110642706          194711071019570642R 1/812.5000000
00010         L           1957110642706          194711071076570623R 1/812.5000000
00010         L           1957110642706          194711071019570623B 1/812.5000000
```

I have a description of the data that tells me what and where all the variables are in this file by starting position in each row, like this:

```
Start position   item length   name
1                    7         code1
8                    8         filler
16                   1         code2
```

So following that I can find the variables. I have isolated the variables in the example below:

```
" 00008 ",        "L","       ",    "19571106","42706","          ","19471107","10","19561030","R 1/8","12.5000000"
```

Unfortunately, some variables have no space between them, others have a few filler spaces, and there is lots of missing data throughout. My question is, how can I go about loading this in a predictable manner? Using `readtable(...,fill=TRUE)` does not recognize the right number of columns, esp. since some are hidden without any spaces between them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether or not your input file has a fixed structure.  Does it have a fixed structure?  If it does, then I would just read the data into R, and deal with it later in R.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do you mean? Every row is the same throughout the input file. Do you mean read it in as say a one column data.frame and then split it? How could I accomplish that?

Comment: What characters are separating the columns of your data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's totally arbitrary, sometimes no characters sometimes a certain number of spaces (see `filler` from the second code chunk), but it is the same across every row

Comment: You would need to know what sort of characters would separate each column.  You can perhaps use a regular expression which would cover the sorts of separators which appear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is not any specific character(s). Sometimes two columns are stuck together like `1957110642706` which is actually `19571106` and `42706` and sometimes there is one, two, or any number of spaces between columns. I have that information, but don't know how I can use it to split the data row by row.